# Gazebo missing methods GetDamping() and GetUseCFMDamping() for joints

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do I find out the damping of a joint in Gazebo?
There is a SetDamping method for joints, but no GetDamping method.
dampingCoefficient is a protected attribute, so I don't know how to access it.
Thanks
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2250/gazebo-missing-methods-getdamping()-and-getusecfmdamping()-for-joints/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/629/add-getdamping-and-getusecfmdamping).  Without direct access to gazebo API, one can also get the robot parameters from robot URDF stored in ROS parameter `/robot_description` (just the damping coefficient, not `use_cfm_damping`).

Non-compilable pseudo-code below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <urdf/model.h>
#include <urdf/link.h>
...
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init( argc, argv, "get_robot_description");
  ros::NodeHandle rosNode;
  std::string urdfString;
  rosNode.getParam("/robot_description", urdfString);
  urdf::Model urdfModel;
  urdfModel.initString(urdfString);
  std::cout << urdfModel->getLink("l_leg_lax")->dynamics->damping << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0